# Vertical White Space after Diagrams

Tags: bug, formatting

I find it difficult to go through the answers with diagram viewers because of the large white space between the end of the moves and the `Start`, `Back` menu... But that's not always the case.

For instance, in this [post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29417/why-are-world-class-engines-playing-like-this), there is no such space in the question, but there are spaces in my answer. I tried to understand why but I failed. Is it me or a kind of bug?

Answer (score 2):

**The "vertical white space" after diagrams is a text box for showing the annotation.**

The reason why the diagrams on the question and the rest of your answer don't show is, there's no annotation. However, the first diagram in your answer has not only 1, but 3 annotations:

```
[FEN "rnb1k1nr/ppp2ppp/4p3/3pP3/1b1P3q/2N3P1/PPP4P/R1BQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1"]
[title "Position after 9. g3"]

9... Qd8! {was played and Lc0 has a pawn down and Stockfish plays to win with Qd8!} (9... Qe4? {is the obvious move but} 10.Kf2 Qxh1 (10...Bxc3 11.bxc3) 11.h3!! { and White equalizes! } 11...Bxc3 12.bxc3 Qe4 13.Bd3 Qh1 14.Bf1=)
```

1. [image: was played and Lc0 has a pawn down and Stockfish plays to win with Qd8!]
2. [image: is the obvious move but]
3. [image: and White equalizes!]

Comment: It makes sense thank you! However, I just checked and there is still the vertical white space. I will update my post with a picture.

Comment: I refreshed my page and the problem disappeared! But there was a blank space between the end of the diagram (or the moves) and the menu (so before the annotation box). But now it's ok! If it comes back I will update my post.